# Write Json document to mongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a CSV file which contains

```
Name, EmployeID
Kishore, 235
```

I need to read Name & EmployeID from above csv file, update name and EmployeID in below JSON and write updated Json to mongodb collection.

```
{    
    "name": kishore,
    "EmployeID": "235",
    "Gender": "Male",
}
```

Can you please help me with any code snippet using C#

Appreciate your help

Comment: Can you please explain the role of the JSON in this regard? Does it mean that you want to import the CSV and create/update documents in MongoDB?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, For example
Employee is the collection name in Mongodb. 
Using MongoShell, we can execute below command to insert a document.
db.employee.insert({name: "kishore", EmployeID: 235, Gender:"Male })

Similarly, I am looking for insertion of below document using C# code and document values(only name and EmployeID is ready from csv) 
Gender is constant value "Male" in document.
{name: "kishore", EmployeID: 235, Gender:"Male }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest form to mimic the `insert` statement from your comment is to use a collection of type `BsonDocument` and insert the document like this:

```
var client = new MongoClient("MONGODB_CONNSTR");
var db = client.GetDatabase("MONGODB_DB_NAME");
var employees = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("employees");
await employees.InsertOneAsync(new BsonDocument
            {
                { "EmployeeId", 235 },
                { "Name", "kishore" },
                { "Gender", "Male" }
            });
```

This creates the following document:

```
{  
  "_id": {    
    "$oid": "62d7b6d25c248b9684eee64d"  
  },  
  "EmployeeId": 235,
  "Name": "kishore",
  "Gender": "Male"
}
```

Comment: You can also use automatic object mapping, see an example here.
https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/blob/main/dotnet/01%20-%20Begin/02%20-%20Simple.cs